# Renaming bunch of files that has single quotes in Python

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to rename some files in a directory, it works fine, except files that contain single quotes(') and they will not change.

```
for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        os.rename(file, file[7:])
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you rename files that contain single quotes?

Comment: you can first try using the regex library and removing the single quotes from the files' names then coninue to run it normally.

Comment: @zenalc files do not change

Comment: @penguin the problem is python does not count them as valid files names, I think.

Comment: @Mahdi which is why I am saying you should set up a conditional statement and use regex to remove the single quotes and/or other symbols as well from the file names then continue to rename the file as you do normally

Comment: @penguin, please send your working example as an answer.

Comment: @Mahdi actually in fact, doesn't seem we need to use regex, you can just try using this `replace` like this `file.replace("'","")` whereby it removes the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily:

```
for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if "'" in file:
            os.rename(file, file.replace("'", ""))
```

This will only rename files that contain a `'`, and will rename those with the original name, but with the single quotes removed via the `replace` call. Hope that helps, happy coding!